# Create relationship from lookup table in Ne04j and Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

New to Neo4j and Cypher and having troubles with a relationship. I may have my data structured incorrectly, but what I would like to do is to create relationships between nodes based on a lookup table. I have done many searches but am not finding something that will work with my situation, which maybe based on my minimal experience with Neo4j.

I have three tables (outlined below), the first table has goals, the second company names, and the third is the relationship between the goals and the company. For example, company ABC want to be green (company)-[WANT_TO_BE]->(goal)

Is this possible in Neo4j, using a lookup table to create relationships? If so, what is the best approach to do so, the examples I find for relationships do not cover this type of example.

**Goal table**

```
goalName
efficient
green
reduce fuel
```

**Company table**

```
companyName
ABC
EFG
XYZ
```

**goal2comp table**

```
goalName, companyName
efficient, ABC
efficient, XYZ
green, ABC
green, EFG
reduce fuel, XYZ
reduce fuel, EFG
```

Comment: Are you asking if modelling this data in neo4j is possible or are you asking how you can import your data from an RDB to neo4j?

Comment: More is it possible to model this data in neo4j. Side question would be is the right approach, or would my data need to be restructured to show the relationships in neo4j

Answer (score 1):

It is completely doable. Here is an example:

```
MERGE (abc:Company {name: "ABC"})
MERGE (efg:Company {name: "EFG"})
MERGE (efficient:Goal {name: "efficient"})
MERGE (green:Goal {name: "green"})
MERGE (abc)-[:WANT_TO_BE]->(efficient)
MERGE (efg)-[:WANT_TO_BE]->(green)
```

UPDATE:
If you have csv files you want to import to neo4j, you can find everything you need here:
https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/

Comment: Thank you for this example! This would be identifying each individual relationship. Is there a way to use the lookup table as a means to connect the relationship, rather than spelling out the each company and goal? So something like where company goalName from goal2comp table is equal to goalName in Goal table AND companyName from goal2comp table is equal to companyName in Company table create relationship WANT_TO_BE

Comment: that means you are looking for a way to somehow access your tables and then create the graph out of it. Where are your tables now? In a sql db? in csv files?

Comment: I have all my tables as csv. The goal and company tables have been loaded into neo4j

Comment: Ok cool. I added some links to the answer. Loading CSVs to neo4j is pretty easy and standard.